# Storing multiply objects, or instances in one array index

Tags: java

Is it possible in java to store multiple objects in one array index. For example object1 and object2 which are string variables can be referenced by array[1].

```
String[] text = new String []
text[1]="rabbit" 
text[1]="horse"
```

So now if I outputted text[1] it would output both strings "rabbit" and "horse".

And is it possible for one object to be reference several array indexs. For example say that object1 = array[1] and array[2].

I'm more interest in the first example. And if they are possible can you please give me an example of this in action.

Answer (score 1):

The way you showed is impossible. text[1] in your example is a reference to exatcly one String object, so you are overriding one reference (to rabbit) with a reference to another String (horse).

Storing two Strings in objects[0]:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[]{new String[]{"a","b"}, null, null};
```

Storing two references as two consecutive fields in an array (one object is referenced several array indexes):

```
Object o = new String("a");
objects[1] = o;
objects[2] = o;
```

Another solution for you:

```
Object[] text = new Object[]{new ArrayList<String>(), null, null};
text[0].add("rabbit");
text[0].add("horse");
```

Answer (score 0):

First one you can do with 2 dimensional array like [][] array of string array
Second one you can do.just an info, Strings are immutable object once you change they become another object

Comment: Could you give me an example of this?

Comment: like that                                                                 String[][] arrays = new String[10][2]; 
arrays[0][0] = "first";
arrays[0][1] = "second";

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to hv multipl ibjects on same index. Second is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> So now if I outputted text[1] it would output both strings "rabbit" and "horse".

No this won't work because `String` is an `Object` and since java object references can hold only one reference to an object at a time, it won't be possible. 
So either your `text[1]` will reference a `String` with characters *rabbit* or *horse*

You have to review your application/method design and you can use some other API Classes which can help achieve your need such as `ArrayList`

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
myList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
myList.get(0).add("rabbit");
myList.get(0).add("horse");
```

Here you have a list of your *chained* strings in some index and you can get them by accessing that item.